# Does Weblogic 12c support Sun Jdk 1.5?

Tags: java, weblogic

I want to migrate my project from IBM websphere 6.1 to oracle weblogic 12c and my project has been developed on Jbuilder, which only supports jdk 1.5. Can I use jdk 1.5 to run it on Weblogic 12c?

Answer (score 2):

No. Java 6 and up according to the [support matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-1211x-certmatrix-1395408.xls) linked to from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html) the supported platforms are

> Oracle JDK 1.6.0_29+
>
> Oracle JDK 1.7.0_02+
>
> IBM JDK 7 (SR1+)
>
> IBM JDK 6 (SR9 FP2 or higher)
>
> Oracle JRockit 6 Update 29 R28.2+

On various platforms. Nothing earlier then 1.6.0_29 is on the list.

Comment: Hi Elliott, can you please check this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988396/ejb-application-deployment-in-weblogic-12c?